# scikit-learn: don't separate hyphenated words while tokenization

Tags: python, regex, scikit-learn, nltk

I am using the `CountVectorizer` and don't want to separate hyphenated words into different tokens. I have tried passing different pregex patterns into the `token_pattern` argument, but haven't been able to get the desired result.

Here's what I have tried:

```
pattern = r''' (?x)         # set flag to allow verbose regexps 
([A-Z]\.)+          # abbreviations (e.g. U.S.A.)
| \w+(-\w+)*        # words with optional internal hyphens
| \$?\d+(\.\d+)?%?  # currency & percentages
| \.\.\.            # ellipses '''

text = 'I hate traffic-ridden streets.'
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english',token_pattern=pattern)
analyze = vectorizer.build_analyzer()
analyze(text)
```

I have also tried to use `nltk`'s `regexp_tokenize` as suggested in an earlier question but it's behaviour seems to have changed as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355046/using-nltk-regex-example-in-scikit-learn-countvectorizer

Comment: @AbhinavArora I have already had a look at that solution. The solution doesn't work with NLTK' most recent version, i.e. 3.0.2

Comment: if you are ok to use other than regex. this can be achieved with rake.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple things to note. The first is that adding in all of those spaces, line breaks and comments into your pattern string makes all of those characters part of your regular expression. See here:

```
import re
>>> re.match("[0-9]","3")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x104caa920>
>>> re.match("[0-9] #a","3")
>>> re.match("[0-9] #a","3 #a")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x104caa718>
```

The second is that you need to escape special sequences when constructing your regex pattern within a string. For example `pattern = "\w"` really needs to be `pattern = "\\w"`. Once you account for those things you should be able to write the regex for your desired tokenizer. For example if you just wanted to add in hyphens something like this will work:

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
>>> pattern = "(?u)\\b[\\w-]+\\b"
>>> 
>>> text = 'I hate traffic-ridden streets.'
>>> vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english',token_pattern=pattern)
>>> analyze = vectorizer.build_analyzer()
>>> analyze(text)
[u'hate', u'traffic-ridden', u'streets']
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  This simple change solved (prevented) the splitting of hyphenated words (e.g., miR-200): cv = CountVectorizer(token_pattern='(?u)\\b[\\w-]+\\b', analyzer='word')

Comment: if we have multiple cases like, if we want to add @ , '.' to regex, Does this 
     pattern = "(?u)\\b[\\w-@.]+\\b" work ?